# Callouts text highcharts alignment issue

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Im trying to display callouts on my Highcharts and noticed some alignment issue.

Without the CSS it works good, but when I add the CSS it does not look good.

Here is my content  -

Without the CSS implementation - where renderer.label useHTML is set to false.

HTML Code:-

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">



<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
body {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
}

div.callout {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  /*float: left;*/
  z-index: 1;
}

div.callout {
  background-color: #444;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444, #444);
  position: relative;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999;
  margin: 25px;
  min-height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
  /*box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2) inset;*/
}

.callout::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 0.8em solid transparent;
  position: absolute;
}

.callout.top::before {
  /*left: 45%;*/
  bottom: -20px;
  border-top: 11px solid #444;
}

.callout.bottom::before {
  /*left: 45%;*/
  top: -20px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #444;
}

.callout.left::before {
  right: -20px;
  top: 40%;
  border-left: 10px solid #444;
}

.callout.right::before {
  /*left: -20px;*/
  top: 40%;
  border-right: 10px solid #444;
}

.callout.top-left::before {
  /*left: 7px;*/
  bottom: -20px;
  border-top: 10px solid #444;
}

.callout.top-right::before {
  /*right: 7px;*/
  bottom: -20px;
  border-top: 10px solid #444;
}
```

Jquery:-

```
    $(function() {
            categories = ["09/07/2016 00:00","09/07/2016 00:01","09/07/2016 00:02","09/07/2016 00:03","09/07/2016 00:04"]
            rate_1 = [0.8,0.54,0.6,0.3,0.4]
            rate_2 = [0.33,0.16,0.33,0.3,0.38]
            rate_3 = [0.03,0.04,0.05,0.03,0.01]

    var addCallout = function(chart) {
    $('.dL').remove();
            var xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
            yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],

            series = chart.series[0],
            point = series.data[0]; 
            console.log('xAxis == ', xAxis)
            console.log('yAxis == ', yAxis.toPixels)
            console.log('series == ', series)
            console.log('point == ', point)       
            console.log(point.plotY)
            console.log(point.plotX)

             var a = chart.renderer.label('<div class="callout top">This is the callout text!</div>',  point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + 10, 
                point.plotY + chart.plotTop - 20, 'callout',null, null, true).add();

            console.log('a',a);
    };

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
  // type: 'bar',
  events: {
    load: function() {          
      addCallout(this);
    },
    redraw: function() {
      addCallout(this);
    },
  }
},
            title: {
                text: 'Spikes Graph',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            }
            ,
             events: {
                load: function() {                          

                // addCallout(this);
            },
                redraw: function() {
                addCallout(this);
            },
            }
            ,
            series: [{
                turboThreshold: 2000 // to accept point object configuration
            }],
            xAxis: {
                categories: categories,
                tickInterval: 60,
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Error Rate'
                },
                min: 0,
                max: 5,
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }],
                labels:{
                    format : '{value} %'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [
                // {turboThreshold: 2000 },
                {
                    name: 'Rate-1',
                    data: rate_1,
                    turboThreshold: 2000,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    useHTML: true,                        
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold'
                    },                        
                },
                }, {
                    name: 'Rate-2',
                    data: rate_2,
                    turboThreshold: 2000,
                    lineWidth: 1
                }, {
                    name: 'Rate-3',
                    data: rate_3,
                    turboThreshold: 2000,
                    lineWidth: 1
                }

            ]
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4qbhjt72/

With CSS implementation - where renderer.label useHTML is set to true.

https://jsfiddle.net/4qbhjt72/1/

Comment: What would you like to achieve? Right now in your css you are setting padding and margin, which is 'moving' your text so it is in another place. Here you can see the alignment when you will remove margin and padding from your callout: https://jsfiddle.net/4qbhjt72/2/

Comment: Thanks..The callout should be displayed above the point.

Comment: So you can move your callout so it will meet your requirements: https://jsfiddle.net/4qbhjt72/4/